# Could position independent code save memory space?

Tags: operating-system, dynamic-linking

In my understanding, the Position-independent code can save disk space because it will not load library in the compiling time and can reduce startup cost because it will load the lib code only when need them to run. Therefore, as every process using the same lib function will load it in their address space, how could this method save memory?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that I have a shared library formatted to work on whatever system I am using. That shared library is position independent.

By being PIC, it can be mapped anywhere in the virtual address space.

If I have 10 processes using that shared library simultaneously, there can be one copy in physical memory with multiple virtual addresses mapping to the same physical addresses.

IF the code is not PIC, it requires the loader to make fixes to the library when it is run. These fixes cannot be shared a across processes, requiring multiple copies of the code in memory.